# Headers not showing up using to_xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-excel

I'm using the gem [to_xls](https://github.com/splendeo/to_xls) and it's great to generate xls files from activerecords. But for some reason I'm not able to get headers to show up.

[image]

Here's the controller:

```
  format.xls {
    send_data @tickets.to_xls(
      :columns => [:created_at, :title, {:category => :title}, {:group => :name}, {:location => :name}, :starts, :target, {:requestor => :full_name}, :percent_complete, :recurring, :cost, :spent, :task_level],
      :headers => [:created, :name, :category, :group, :location, :start_date, :target_date, :requestor, :percent_complete, :recurring, :cost, :spent, :task_level]
    )
  }
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have (:headers => false) anywhere would you?

Comment: nope. just what you see there.

Comment: Only possible other thing I can think of is there is not the correct amount of :headers to :columns :S Looks fine to me though

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking but I've counted them like 4 times to see if there was the right amount.

Answer (score 0):

to_xls plugin does not show headers with associated models because it can't understand attribute names.

You can try to give strings to headers instead of attributes:

```
format.xls {
    send_data @tickets.to_xls(
      :columns => [:created_at, :title, {:category => :title}, {:group => :name}, {:location => :name}, :starts, :target, {:requestor => :full_name}, :percent_complete, :recurring, :cost, :spent, :task_level],
      :headers => ["created", "name", "category", "group", "location", "start_date", "target_date", "requestor", "percent_complete", "recurring", "cost", "spent", "task_level"]
    )
}
```

Comment: I actually contacted the creator of the gem and he said it was a flaw. It's fixed now and working the way I had it in my question. Thanks!